# How to create a background process on iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a background task to execute some action with a timer, but don't kill that task when app is killed (for example I double click Home button and remove the app from that "list").

Comment: Short answer; you can't. There are specific background modes available for things such as location and audio/video. These are listed in the iOS application programming guide.  You can schedule a local notification to display at a specific time.

Comment: Paulw11's 100% correct. Apple's position is to try not to give developers enough leeway to abuse the trust of its users; if sometimes that means obstructing a legitimate use case then so be it. The gain outweighs the loss. A million ways that bad or malicious developers might abuse arbitrary background processes occur almost instantly, so Apple whitelists what it will allow and implements that for you.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained why you want to do this.  There may be some other way to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Timers don't run after an app is killed in iOS.  Killing an app causes the OS to kill all of the apps timers, run loops, and background threads.  All your app's executable code is likely deallocated from memory, so is not even around to run.

You could schedule a local (or remote) notification, but that won't execute any code in your app without user interaction.  If there is an IFTTT app running on the device, and not killed, perhaps it could be scripted to launch your app periodically.